# C# nuance omnipage OCR SDK Engine.SetLicenseKey()

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, ocr

im using nuance omnipage OCR SDK.

While compiling got error: Engine initialization error, or no appropriate license. I found that probably i should use Engine.SetLicenseKey() method.

What file and license key should i provide to Engine.SetLicenseKey()?

```
    try
    {
        List<OCR_Error> ocrErrors = new List<OCR_Error>();
        System.Console.Write("** Title: Nuance Capture Development System CSharp Sample01 Application **\n");
        System.Console.Write("Initializing the ENGine -- Engine.Init\n");
        Engine.SetLicenseKey("licenseFile.lcx", "licenseKey");
        Engine.Init("companyName", "projectName");
        if (Engine.RECERR == RECERR.API_INIT_WARN)
        {
            ocrErrors.Add(new OCR_Error()
            {
                Message = "Module initialization warning. One or more recognition modules haven't been initialized properly.",
                InnerMessage = "For more information, see Engine.ModulesInfo"
            });
            return;
        }
        string inputFileName = @"D:\3141864.pdf";
        string inputFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(inputFileName);
        string outputFilePath = inputFilePath.Replace('.', '_') + @".pdf";
        if (File.Exists(outputFilePath))
            File.Delete(outputFilePath);
        File.Create(outputFilePath);

        using (SettingCollection settings = new SettingCollection())
        {
            using (Document doc = new Document(inputFilePath))
            {
                int sourcePagesCount = doc.PageCount;
                for (int i = 0; i < sourcePagesCount; i++)
                {
                    using (Page page = new Page(inputFilePath, i, settings))
                    {
                        page.Preprocess();
                        page.Recognize();
                        using (Document oputputDocument = new Document(outputFilePath, 0, settings))
                        {
                            oputputDocument.InsertPage(page, i);
                            oputputDocument.Save(outputFilePath);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Console.Write(e.Message);//Error: License Manager error.
    }
    finally
    {
        System.Console.Write("Free all resources allocated by the Engine -- Engine.ForceQuit\n");
        Engine.ForceQuit();
        System.Console.Write("End of Sample01 application\n");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: please share your code where you are getting the error so that we can help you

Comment: @SimonPrice, Engine.Init("companyName", "projectName");
Here i get an error

Comment: @SimonPrice, added source code

Answer (score 1):

If you bought this software it should come with proper documentation and/or support about how to load your license file and key in code. Check the docs or contact them.

If you didn't buy this software, it seems it requires a valid license file and key. You might need to purchase a license.

If you bought this software without documentation and support, consider your money lost.